# What fields does SDL Tridion 2011 search use?

Tags: tridion

I have never had practical success when using the search feature in Tridion (SDL Tridion 2011). I am looking at a list of components. I enter **some** of the text for one those component's name and the search does not find it. I have to use the **exact name** of the component for it to find it.

What fields does it search using my criteria?

Is there a wild card symbol I can use or a setting to make it a "contains" query?

Comment: Which version of Tridion do you use? That is relevant to this question, since the underlying search engine changed from Verity to Solr in Tridion 2011.

Comment: Is the Tridion Content Manager Search Indexer running on your system?

Comment: @Puf, I made edit to point out our version is 2011. I do see results if I key in the exact name of the component, therefore, would that imply the Indexer is running?

Comment: Try running the TcmReIndex.exe tool located in the Tridion/bin folder to re-index all your sites.  It can take a long time to run...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Search Indexer should index all fields of every components as well as text in binaries (PDFs, MS Word Docs etc). I have a running instance of SDL Tridion 2011 and can confirm that it does in fact give results from both binary and normal component content.

I am not entirely sure of the inner workings of the newer SolR version of Tridion, but I imagine that Titles and Full text are indexed separately.

It could be that your indexer is not actually running properly, I have seen the service  appear to be in the running state, but not actually processing messages in the Search Queue.  Try opening the Purge Queue tool (Normally located at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\bin\TcmPurgeQueue.exe"), and see if there are lots of messages waiting in the Search Queue. If there are, it may be that items are not being processed properly, try hitting refresh and see if the number is going down.

For a wildcard, you should just be able to use a `'*'`. I just tested putting the string `"Rampusplong"` in a component filed, and can confirm that searching for `"Rampusplong"` or `"Rampus*"` or `"*ampusplo*"` return my result, but "Rampus" returns no results.

Comment: Title and Description fields are indexed separately. Infact all the fields are indexed and Tridion can search on specific fields. You use access the solr admin to check whether your components been indexed. Also you can search using the Solr Admin Panel.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `*` for wild cards as Chris mentions. See some reserved word options below (source: the SDL Welcome "Getting to Know SDL Tridion" help pages) for other options to try.

**identifier** (e.g. `tcm:19-123-8`)

**search operators**

- `AND`
- `OR`
- `NOT`
- `IN` (e.g. "someword IN title", where title is the component's XML)

**exact phrases** delimited with " (e.g. "Mad cookie")

**wildcards**

- `*` for wildcard, multiple characters (I've sometimes needed this on supposed full matches)
- `?` for single

**special characters**
   `+` `-` `!` `(` `)` `{` `}` `[` `]` `^` `"` `~` `*` `?` `:` `\`
(help file doesn't say much more except to escape with double quotes)

**reserved words** (escape with \ regardless of capitalization)

- `CONTAINS`
- `NEAR`
- `SENTENCE`
- `PARAGRAPH`
- `PHRASE`
- `IN`
- `MATCHES`
- `STARTS`
- `SUBSTRING`
- `ENDS`
- `AND`
- `OR`
- `NOT`

You can also search in multimedia as well as metadata, schema, and the other visible search options by clicking on the advanced search (down arrow next to search).

At least in older versions (R5.3 specifically and possibly 2009), I've seen items outside of regular creation (via VBScript) skip getting indexed. Re-index if that's the case, but not sure with 2011.

Comment: It seems odd that the creation method would affect this, as the API is responsible internally for queuing search items. I wonder if it was simply a question of waiting for the service to catch up.

Comment: It was some VBScript creating multimedia, running on the CMS which was  then content ported (was this business connector in 5.3?) from dev to stg to production CMS. I'm not sure what part of that (script or content port) had an issue, but at least for that one time I had issues searching for such "imported" items. Maybe it was fluke. If anyone can confirm, feel free to update that last paragraph. Otherwise, I'll edit accordingly as heresy. :-)