# Error when running TcmReindex.exe

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am currently trying to get search working in my Tridion 2011 installation. I read in [another article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452589/what-fields-does-sdl-tridion-2011-search-use) that I should run the TcmReIndex.exe tool in the Tridion/bin folder to re-index all my sites. So I tried this and it failed with a message box giving the following details

```
Unable to get list of Publication items.
Unable to Intialize TDSE object.
The wait operation timed out
Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=21054; handshake=35; 
The wait operation timed out
A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_TRUSTEES_GETTRUSTEEETOKEN"
```

I have four fairly large publications (100 000+ items in total) which I am trying to index.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running the tool "As Administrator" or as yourself. This sometimes makes a difference

Comment: Running as administrator. If I try running it as myself I get a different error saying I don't have permission to access certain parts of the configuration.

Comment: Can you confirm everything else in your CM is working? Can you try creating a new Target Type in the CM (You can delete it if it works). I am having a hunch it is some kind of COM communication error, as TDSE is COM based, and most of the CM is now .NET

Comment: @ChrisSummers I can create target types, pages etc. Everything but publishing works (this is a seperate issue)

Comment: @RamG I am using Tridion 2011 SP2

Comment: SP2? you meant to be SP1. I have a feeling that your DB query is timing out. Did you your database stats up to date? Try updating the stats on your DB and also you can increase the time out value from `Tridion MMC` --> `Timeout Settings`

Comment: Ah yes, SP1! Is increasing the timeout wise? My timeout settings are rendering = 120000ms, establishing a connection = 60s, executing a long query = 120s, executing a query = [blank]

Comment: You may want to run some DB maintenance also - Updating the indexes and statistics may speed things up

Comment: executing a query = [blank], which is 30 secs default. you could increase this number to 60 or 90 then restart all tridion components to take this effect. But the key is DB maintenance, running the stats and optimizing the indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't come to anything conclusive but it seems like my issue may have been a temporary one as it just started working. I did increase all timeouts in `Tridion MMC` > `Timeout Settings` by 100 times their amounts but I suspect that this wasn't the issue, when it works the connection is almost instant.

If anyone else has this issue

1. Restart the computer the content manager is installed on, try again.
2. Wait an hour or two, try again.
3. Increase timeouts, try again.

I've run the process a few more times and it seems to be working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I get "Unable to Intialize TDSE object." errors, I typically write a small test script using VBScript, and try running it on the CMS server. Whilst this does not directly solve the problem, it often gives some insight into the issue by logging information in the event viewer. Try creating a `test.vbs` file as follows and running it:

```
Set tdse = CreateObject("TDS.TDSE")
tdse.initialize()
msgbox(tdse.User.Description)
Set tdse = Nothing
```

If it throws any errors, please let me know, and it may help us solve the problem. If it gives you a popup with your user description, then I am completely barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Then consider this the wrong tree - it could be a bogus error message - I would follow @Ram's timeout theory. Good luck